# SetTextFormat, font and bullets

Tags: actionscript-3

If I set tf.bullet = true and then SetTextFormat(tf,x,y), it creates a bullet, but only if the character at position x is in a font that has a bullet character defined.  If it doesn't then there's a blank where the bullet is supposed to be.  Any ideas on how to set just the bullet to a given font.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this before you setTextFormat():

```
tf.font = "AFontWithBullets";
```

Comment: But then that will change the font of the label, which is not what I want.  Maybe you meant as a kludge where afterwards I change the label back to the original font and see if the bullet sticks.  Incidentally the only reason I'm still up is that I found an unrelated problem where <p>...<br></p> in Text.htmlText automatically cuts off everything after the ending </p>.  Read somewhere that textfield.multiline has to be set to True (which it is by default with MX::Text) but also that it has to be set to True before htmlText is set, which I don't have control over. I think its a bug in Flex